# If url already exists in url table in mysql. Break operation in php script

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code which echos the body and title in the browser, this then gets stored to the database but I wanted to know how I can add a statement which checks to see if the url is already in the url table from the repository database. Something like (echo "url already exists")

```
$url = $_GET["url"];
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$html = file_get_html($url);
echo $html->find('body', 0);
echo $html->find('title', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make the url unique in your database.

Or do a `select` first or do an `insert on duplicate key update`, etc.

Comment: the url is a text datatype though

Comment: @Praneet Sharma text or varchar?

Comment: @Praneet Sharma Then change it to varchar or use one of the other methods.

Comment: @Praneet Sharma It´s only 255 for mysql < 5.0.3, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html